# How to use custom location build configuration file in tizen gbs build?

Tags: tizen

From gbs build wiki it says, if a **Specific_Project/.gbs.conf** file exists, the configuration in that file is used when building the project with GBS. If not, the default GBS configuration in **~/.gbs.conf** is used.

How can I use a configuration file exist in a custom location like \home\pub\files.gbs.conf when building a project with gbs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -c parameter

```
gbs -c <gbs-conf-file-full-path>
```